# AC Electrical Safety Guidelines/ Legislation for in-house ATE

Tags: ac

I am designing an in-house measurement and control system and we have decided to use a Traco AC/ DC converter.  We are taking UK mains 240V AC and converting it to 12V for use in powering a number of measurement devices and an industrial PC.

I am using the [TXM 035-112](http://www.tracopower.com/products/browse-by-category/show/ac-dc-power-supplies/metal-enclosure/txm/1/) AC/DC converter which means the AC must be wired to the AC/DC converter rather than using a kettle lead, (UK Mains plug to C13 IEC Socket).  It works fine, there are no problems but I am concerned in case we are not complying with the UK electrical safety standards, (e.g. Do we need to earth the [control system chassis](http://www.schneider-electric.com/en/product-range/2539-spacial-s3x/)?  Is an MCB required? Do I need to place electrical hazard stickers)

Does anyone know the standards that must be followed when using screw terminal AC/ DC converters?  (We have been referred by SteveG & Traco to IEC 60950-1 (£620) which we don't yet have, (why do safety documents cost so much?).

Ideal would be an xyz of what needs to be done according to EU law.

Comment: UK mains is 240 V AC, not 24VAC. You might want to explain "kettle lead" for the international audience and provide links to the PSU datasheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are electrical safety standards that must be followed for your product as a whole. These are usually EU standards rather than UK standards. Unless there is a product specific standard you probably should use EN60950 and all of its amendments. I'm not aware that there is a specific standard for using a an AC/DC module, its use will be covered in the main standard.

It is difficult to give advise about the safety of your product without a sample of the product and a thorough knowledge of how it is intended to be used. And anyway this site is not meant for that. You asked a few specific questions:

**Do we need to earth the chassis?**

You should must earth the chassis of the AC/DC module. This is for both electrical safety and EMC. The earth connection is often used to absorb high frequency interference coming from the AC/DC module, and also to absorb high energy transients going to it. Generally you must also earth the metal chassis of your product.

**Is an MCB required?**

Usually, no. However, you should use a glass fuse in the Live conductor. Most people would use a Fused Terminal Block for the mains connection.

Answer (score 1):

> Do we need to earth the chasis?

Pin 3 on these modules has a protective earth symbol on them: -

[image]

This means it must be earthed. I would also advice you to read the data sheet and follow the link on page 3 that takes you to the certification documents - these should give a fuller indication of YOUR obligations when using your particular model.

Comment: apologies, I meant to state the control system chassis not the AC/DC converter.

Comment: Does the traco have a metal base that is attached to your main chassis for cooling purposes?

Comment: the traco supply is connected to a mounting plate which is connected to the chassis and hence grounded. The grounding is an example.  For example if I do 4 of the 5 required things and someone injures themselves, that is not good.  I need to have all the t's crossed and i's dotted.  Sorry for not stating this sufficiently in the first post.